# NSString caseInsensitiveCompare confusing ordering

Tags: objective-c, osx-yosemite

I'm seeing something wired when using NSString caseInsensitiveCompare.
For below two strings:

```
NSString *str1 = @"Výkazy do poisťovní";
NSString *str2 = @"Vyšlé faktúry 2007.xls";
```

I use NSString caseInsensitiveCompare to compare them,

```
    int ci1 = [str1 caseInsensitiveCompare:str2];
    int ci2 = [str2 caseInsensitiveCompare:str1];
```

Since they are different strings, I expect above code should give me 1 and -1. But surprisingly both ci1 and ci2 are 1. How can this happen???

Comment: How do you know they are both 1? What does NSLog say?

Comment: I tested it and that's what NSLog gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Always use **current** locale when its a string used for display.

```
NSString *str1 = @"Výkazy do poisťovní";
NSString *str2 = @"Vyšlé faktúry 2007.xls";

int ci1 = [str1 compare:str2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str1.length) locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
int ci2 = [str2 compare:str1 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str2.length) locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Comment: The current locale is used by default.

Comment: @rmaddy, no it isn't. You either have to use one of the methods which take a locale argument or you need to use `-localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`. The docs for `-caseInsensitiveCompare:` even say so.

Comment: My mistake. It is the system locale that is used by default, not the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

You've found a bug. You can't use simple-minded `caseInsensitiveCompare:` in this situation. You have to turn off diacritics and case manually, like this:

```
NSComparisonResult ci1 = [str1 compare:str2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,str1.length)];
NSComparisonResult ci2 = [str2 compare:str1 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,str2.length)];
```

Comment: Plain caseInsensitiveCompare: should give consistent results for _any_ data.

Comment: @gnasher729 Of course it should. That's why, in my answer, I call it a bug.

Comment: Yep, looks like a bug to me unless there is some super wired ordering with diacritic. NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch does seems fix the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting problem - I never noticed it before. Do you want to file a bug report with Apple, or would you like me to do it?